# Change django templates path

Tags: django

I'm using django-registration-redux and want to change style of templates. For this i take template/registration folder from github and added to my folder with templates. How to tell django search templates in my project folder

```
D:\django\blogRodion\blogRodion\blog\templates\registration\
```

instead of

```
 D:\django\blogRodion\blogRodion\env\lib\site-packages\registration\templates\registration\
```

Comment: Can you place your `registration` above `django.contrib.admin` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your settings.py Django (1.8+)

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
   {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        'other_dir_path_to_include'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
  },
]
```

for more details see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_DIRS

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I'm jast overwrite source folder.

Comment: create a folders named "templates" at the root level of project and keep your templates in it. It will work.

Comment: This work:  'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog\\templates'),
        ],